# How can I install flask in virtual machine using pip?

Tags: python, virtual-machine

After running the virtual machine, I want to run a python module named `forum.py`. I typed `python forum.py`, but it shows me the following error:

[image]

Comment: `pip install Flask`

Comment: it's not recognize pip also

Answer (score 3):

Log into your virtual machine

```
vagrant ssh
```

Then run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

It will install pip library for you. Then run the following command to install flask

```
pip install flask
```

If you want to know flask installed or not then you can run

```
flask --version
```

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install python-pip
then
pip install Flask

if on ubuntu/debian , 
if on SUSE: zypper install python-pip
otherwise replace the apt-get with yum install